# Why destructor and copy constructor is showing this behavior with array of objects?

Tags: c++

When array was initialized with anonymus objects, destructor is displaying valid values, but I create an array with objects, override copy constructor doesn't call and also destructor is displaying garbage values.

I have tried understanding this by displaying values but still confused.

```
class Check{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        Check()
        {
            this->a = 9999;
            cout << "\n Default Constructor Called \n";
        }
        Check(int i)
        {
            this->a = i;
        }
        Check(const Check & obj)
        {
            cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR\n";
        }
        ~Check()
        {
            cout << this->a<<" DESTRUCTOR  \n";
        }
};

Check b[2] = {Check(5),Check(4)};
Check obj1(2);
Check obj2(3);
Check a[2] = {obj1,obj2};
```

I was expecting the "COPY CONSTRUCTOR" output 4 times but it was only two times and no garbage values. Actual output is shown below:

> ```
> COPY CONSTRUCTOR 
> COPY CONSTRUCTOR 
> 32649 DESTRUCTOR  
> -1330935392 DESTRUCTOR  
> 3 DESTRUCTOR  
> 2 DESTRUCTOR  
> 4 DESTRUCTOR  
> 5 DESTRUCTOR
> ```

Comment: The garbage values are because in the copy constructor you don't initialize `this->a`

Comment: @M.M can you tell me why copy constructor is called for only 2 times?

Comment: Print the value of `a` in each constructor and you'll see why.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel why no copy constructor is calling in this case:Check b[2] = {Check(5),Check(4)};"

Comment: @usamamw141 this is called [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). The objects are constructed directly there, and never copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because of copy elision.

In this case:

```
Check b[2] = {Check(5),Check(4)};
```

Since both values are temporaries, the compiler is allowed (or, in C++17, forced) to optimize the copy away and instead construct the objects in place.

However, in the second case:

```
Check a[2] = {obj1,obj2};
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are not temporaries, so real copies must occur in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
Check b[2] = {Check(5),Check(4)};
```

this syntax means that the constructor arguments for the two array elements are `5` and `4` .  It does not mean that the arguments are temporaries.

`Check(5)` is a *prvalue expression*,  this does not necessarily mean a temporary is materialized. One of the ways a prvalue can be "consumed" is as the initializer for an object of the same type.

This behaviour changed in C++17; prior to that, there was conceptually always a temporary but the temporary could be omitted at the compiler's discretion.